# how to parse a string and make a python dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

i am trying to parse a string and then do some calculations after a making a python dictionary. But i am having issues with it. This is what i have written so far....

```
name = raw_input("Enter name of the file")
if len(name) < 1:
    name = "test.txt"
fh = open(name)

count = dict()
new = ""
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("From "):
        time = line.split()
        time = time[5]
        hr = time.split(":")
        new.append(hr[0])
        count[new] = count.get(new,0) + 1
        print count
```

Basically i want to read a file, select a line based on a particular pattern (line starts with "From" in this case), split the selected lines, again split the selected lines based on ":". Once have the first column (basically two digit numbers example - 09, 11, 24, 11, 11, 11 etc.,), then do a count of numbers and then report the number and then the count. But i am getting error with my code. 
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' on line 14`

Any help?

Comment: You += a string not append to it

Comment: new is a string. append is for lists.

Comment: append is for lists, not strings. And you should really look into Regular Expressions. With just one line you can do the same you're trying to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections
import re

REGEX = r'^From\s+(?:\S\s){4}(\d+):.*$'

file_name = raw_input("Enter the name of the file: ")
if file_name == '':
    file_name = 'test'

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    file_content = f.read() # assuming the file isn't too large

numbers = re.findall(REGEX, file_content, re.MULTILINE)
print collections.Counter(numbers) # count '09' and '009' as different numbers
print collections.Counter([int(i) for i in numbers]) # count '09' and '009' as the same number
```